# Symfony 6 form_widget translations

Tags: php, symfony, twig, locale, symfony6

I've been strugling with setting translation for form's labels in a project in Symfony 6 lately.

I've got ExampleController which passes `$form = $this->createForm(ExampleType::class, $example)` to `templates/example/new.html.twig` including default `_form.html.twig` generated by the `make:crud` command, which looks like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save'|trans) }}</button>
        
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I would like it to stay the way it was generated (using form_widget for the whole $form object) for consistency, if that's possible.

What I've tried was adding a `messages.pl.yaml` file to the translations directory, based on some advices found on the net. Ended up juggling up names back and forth with no luck. I feel like I'm making a really silly mistake here, any help greatly appreciated:

```
example:
    fields:
        name: "Lorem"
        title: "Ipsum"
        description: "Dolor sit amet"
    labels:
        name: "Lorem"
        title: "Ipsum"
        description: "Dolor sit amet"
```

My configuration:

`config/packages/translation.yaml`

```
framework:
    default_locale: pl
```

`php.ini`

```
extension=intl

[intl]
intl.default_locale=pl
```

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1488/how-to-translate-constraint-messages-of-a-symfony-5-form-including-non-mapped-fields

Comment: thank you @ArleighHix, I knew I was missing something obvious

Answer (score 0):

you dont translate the value.. only the fallback:

```
<button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save')|trans }}</button>
```

if `button_label` is the key itself.. then it is just:

```
<button class="btn">{{ "button_label"|trans }}</button>
```

Comment: although it's not an answer to my question, thank you very much for pointing this out too